# wicd-curses problem on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, 14.04, wicd

How to get `wicd-curses` to work on Ubuntu 14.04. This command works great on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this program actually installed? First, try executing:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-curses
```

Comment: No, I cant install it. I got error during installation process.

Comment: What is the output of the error?

Comment: I had no error installing it, but then a screenful when I tried to use it.  So I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the up/down-arror icon in the upper right.  It works fine.

On Raspbian you can't count on that icon, but in Ubuntu 14.04 it is great.

Another advantage of using it is that when you change IP addresses on eth0 it happens immediately.

wicd-curses is not needed.  Which is a darn good thing because it doesn't work.